# Openstack Cinder version not supported

Tags: openstack, cinder, openstack-cinder

I am trying to create a cinder storage with a size of 5Gb and I get the following error.

```
# cinder create 5 --display-name FileStorage
ERROR: Version 3.52 is not supported by the API. Minimum is 3.0 and maximum is 3.50. (HTTP 406) (Request-ID: req-cc838137-0b60-4e72-8abe-a679a55aa399)
```

Is there any way I could get the cinder created ? I cannot change settings in openstack as I am not an admin. How do I go back version to 3.50 ?

Comment: Try using the openstack client instead. https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/pike/cli/command-objects/volume.html

Comment: I am using open stack client

Comment: I solved it by setting OS_VOLUME_API_VERSION env variable to 3.50.

Comment: OpenStack client command would look something like this
> openstack volume create FileStorage --size 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the API version that cinder will use by setting an environment variable :

```
export OS_VOLUME_API_VERSION=3.50
```